# Address pool for Point-to-Site configuration

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

As reference guide for Point-to-Site configuration, I have gone through some links.

The Address pool used by links for P2S configuration is like 172.16.0.0/24, 172.16.25.0/24 and 172.20.20.0/24. All start with 172.

I believe the Address pool can be any independent Public IP. Also, I read the Address pool shouldn’t be overlapped with On-Premises IP and Azure VNet.

Now I have confusion as following.

For example, on-premises IP is like 103.134.x.x, Azure VNet is 12.0.0.0/24, Azure VM Private IP is 52.173.x.x and Virtual Network Gateway’s Address pool is like 172.16.0.0/24, all are independent to each other.

Will all communicate each other by default?

Regards

TekQ

Comment: 52.173.x.x is not a private IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, your client address pool is right. They will communicate with each other.